# How do I run my VS Code extension tests on Circle CI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, circleci

I have written unit tests for my VS Code extension and these run fine locally but I wanted to run them on my Circle CI build.

I am having issues getting this working though, I have looked at the guide to [setting it up on Travis CI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/testing-extensions#_running-tests-automatically-on-travis-ci-build-machines) but that doesn't seem to help.

I have tried installing all the apt packages it seems to need before running the tests, but it still fails and there isn't an error message.

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libxtst6 libxss1 libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libasound2`

```
yarn test v0.24.4
$ node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/test 
### VS Code Extension Test Run ###
Current working directory: /home/circleci/repo
Downloading VS Code into "/home/circleci/repo/.vscode-test/stable" from: https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/1.24.0/linux-x64/stable
Running extension tests: /home/circleci/repo/.vscode-test/stable/VSCode-linux-x64/code /home/circleci/repo/test --extensionDevelopmentPath=/home/circleci/repo --extensionTestsPath=/home/circleci/repo/test
Tests exited with code: 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
Exited with code 1
```

Comment: Whenever you're trying to get help with a CircleCI build, you'll want to share as much of your CircleCI config as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to add `-browsers` to your docker image. So, in config.yml something like:

```
docker:
  # specify the version you desire here
  - image: circleci/node:12.4-browsers
```

where you replace `12.4` with your node version.